# How to navigate in an ios app whose interfaces are created programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am using Xamarin.IOS to develop an IOS app. For some reasons, I decided to create all interfaces pragmatically.

So I have a tab bar controller as root view controller and in each tab, there's a navigation controller which consists of a number of view controllers.

My question is that what is the best way to navigate freely between those view controller across different tabs?

For example:

Tab 1 - Nav layer 1 (View Controller A) - Nav Layer 2 (View Controller B)

Tab 2 - Nav layer 1 (View Controller C) - Nav Layer 2 (View Controller D)

In controller D, when user press a button, I want to switch to Tab 1 and show view controller B, also trigger a process X on Controller B, may be like a refresh of the content.

What would be a good practice to do this?

I know that  I can access "this.tabBarController" to access the tab controller in view controller D(I am having some issue atm that "this.tabBarController" is null when I try to access, but will figure it out separately), but continue from there, how should I nav to view controller B and especially, should I create a method in B that can be called outside to trigger the refresh process X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've read a lot since I asked this and know the answer now. Since no one is answering it, kind of awkward, I will.

Use delegate!

It's like calling methods defined in interfaces, listening to events in .Net. I will update more details tmr.

Will be back!